# If i want to create the XML file, res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml, which file shall I create? XML layout file or value file?

Tags: android, xml

I am a fresh beginner in programming, when I am learning from Android developer website
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

I confused with the type of file, which file shall I create? XML layout file or value file? And what is the difference for both file?

Comment: I wanted to create XML file for the purpose to add Action Button **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any differents. Both are a xml file. Only difference is inside file. In layout file proframmers expect see layouts and in values programmers expect see values. Both should be in correct folders layout or values. Android studio just created 2 buttons to create this xml file to help developers and provide for them some templates with xmlns. That all :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a layout file, because you're creating a menu.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a xml file and add contents like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.app.tweetdemo.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

There is no need to confuse as both layout and values files are xml files and the xml files need to be kept accordingly in their respective folders.